# How and for what purpose did Lorentz come out with his "electron model"?

Tags: electromagnetism

Who suggested to him the idea that charge wasn't really some excess or defect of "electric fluid", but rather something carried by a particle?

Comment: Was this before or after J.J.Thomson's cathode ray experiments?

Comment: The Lorentz-Drude model came after. But I think Lorentz was working on it before Thomson discovery

Comment: The idea of electrons (under various names) was common currency in the second half of 19th century, long before Lorentz proposed his theory in 1892, and Thomson confirmed them experimentally in 1897, see [Wikipedia's history section on electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#Discovery_of_free_electrons_outside_matter). Lorentz described his motivations in detail in his [Nobel lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1902/lorentz/lecture/). Chemical and heating action of light, magneto-optics, cathode rays, etc., were among the targeted phenomena.